# SQL Statement won't work

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Attendance.EventID, Events.[Event Name], Sum(Attendance.Attend) AS SumOfAttend, IIf([SumOfAttend]>30,"Over","Under") AS OverUnder30
```

When i run this SQL statement in Access 2013 Access pops up a parameter box and wants me to the value for SumOfAttend. I want to test the SumOfAttend value that is already calculated and if it is over 30 then display over in another field and if it is under 30 I want it to display under

Thank you

Comment: You have no `from` clause.

Comment: you also need a `GROUP BY` so it knows how to sum `attendance.attend`.  You can't calculate a field value and then refer to its alias in the same query.  Try using `sum(attendance.attend)` instead of `[SumOfAttend]` in `IIF()`

Comment: I can only assume that OP removed the FROM and GROUP BY clause to keep the question brief, otherwise Access would be balking about that before thinking the last field was actually a parameter...

Comment: SELECT Attendance.EventID, Events.[Event Name], Sum(Attendance.Attend) AS SumOfAttend
FROM Events INNER JOIN Attendance ON Events.EventID = Attendance.EventID
GROUP BY Attendance.EventID, Events.[Event Name];
\

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you removed the FROM clause here on purpose... You can use the following SELECT clause to do what you want:

```
SELECT Attendance.EventID, Events.[Event Name], Sum(Attendance.Attend) AS SumOfAttend, IIf(Sum(Attendance.Attend)>30,"Over","Under") AS OverUnder30
```

This way you aren't relying on Access to figure out what you mean by `[SumOfAttend]`